# Texture with transparent areas renders the areas as black - how do I make them transparent?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a very simple 2d square, which I render a game sprite onto from a texture.  This all works quite well, except that the areas that should be transparent in the texture are rendered as black.  How do I render those transparent areas to show the objects behind the square (in this case, the background)?

---

Incase relevant, here's the simple fragment Shader:

```
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vImagePosition;
void main(){
    gl_FragColor =  texture2D(uTexture, vImagePosition);
}
```

And the vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aImagePosition;
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
varying vec2 vImagePosition;
void main(){
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix*aPosition;
    vImagePosition = aImagePosition;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually stumbled across the answer after a couple hours of searching.  You have to turn blending on.  Hope this helps others.

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably prefer to encode you transparent areas as alpha channel so that transparent areas have an smooth transition. If you are only using the black RGB(0,0,0) color, then you should take this into account in your fragment shader. Black doesn't mean without color, means black color. Enable the OpenGL blending state so that the alpha channel coming out of the fragment shader is taken into account when writing the pixel value into the buffer. For example:

```
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vImagePosition;
vec4 color;

void main(){
    color =  texture2D(uTexture, vImagePosition);
    if(color.r == 0 && color.g == 0 && color.b == 0){
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0,0,0,0);
    } else{
        gl_FragColor = color;
    }
}
```

(I have not checked if the above code compiles, it is just to give you an idea).

Comment: I may have been misleading in my language.  I mean to say that the original image has transparency (not black) in the background of the sprites, but OGL is rendering it as black.

I could not get your shader example to link.  It kept erroring out, but I could not locate the error.

Comment: I'm happy you found the problem. That's what I meant with "Enable the OpenGL blending state so that the alpha channel coming out of the fragment shader is taken into account". Cheers.